# What APIs can be used inside transaction processor?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I have questions related what APIs are available inside Hyperledger Composer's transaction processor.  It looks like, the sample only provides obtain assetRegistry, and then registry.update().  I expect that transaction processor is what we call SmartContract. Suppose the transaction is supposed to change the owner. So I want to verity update such that, new owner exists. I wonder if I can use participantRegistry.get() operation inside transaction processor. I checked that resolve() function is not available. So I suspect, transaction processor provides APIs available on composer runtime. But there is no documentation as to what kind of APIs are available for transaction processor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The runtime APIs are in the runtime module. However, the runtime modules appear to have been removed from the publication of the API on the website. Please create an issue for that.

Comment: I'll create an issue.

Comment: There is a copy of the old style jsdocs pages available for now if that helps. I've added a link to the github issue https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/2325